# Isn't the word "shotgun" a self-redundancy?

Tags: etymology, redundancy, portmanteau-words

I was googling the reason for why it's called "*shotgun*" to ride beside the driver when it suddenly hit me - why on Earth is the firearm called "*shotgun*"?!

Is there any other kind of a **gun** than one used for **shooting**?! Why is it called "*shotgun*" instead of just a "*gun*" or a more technical term (9-gauge, barrel gun etc.)?

Comment: By the way, "riding shotgun" derives from the Old West practice of transporting money in stagecoaches with an armed guard riding next to the driver, typically carrying a shotgun.  At the time, the nickname for an "express messenger" with a guard was "shotgun messenger".  The term "ride shotgun" appears to have come into use in Western fiction in the early 20th century.

Comment: I think the elephant in the room is that you are disregarding morphology on purpose. A gun used for shooting would be called a *shootgun* or a *shooting gun*. A *shotgun*, on the other hand, is quite obviously not a gun for shooting, but a gun for shot.

Comment: I have to close this per the very first sentence in the Wikipedia article on [shotguns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun).

Comment: @RegDwigнt You're mistaken. That's the way I interpret(ed) the word, hence the question. Asking **on purpose** a question that can be easily resolved would be waste of everybody's time (border-line trolling). You need to keep in mind that **some** of us aren't NSEs and can miss an "*obvious*" thing (obvious to NSEs, that is). I didn't think of checking for different meanings of "*shot*" because I didn't realize that there could be such. After all - "*gun to make a shot*" => "*shot-gun*".

Comment: This should not be closed. I have learnt two things very useful to know, that I did not previously know. The first comment and the answer are both very informative. It has almost 2000 views since being asked yesterday. Closing this and questions like it is detrimental to this site. I have flagged for moderator attention with the same message.

Comment: @user I agree with you. My guess based on what RegDwigнt said himself is that he (**incorrectly**) assumed that I'm just playing dumb and and intentionally ask a question where the answer is obvious. I believe that RegDwigнt fails to realize that non-NSEs might benefit from it, even if for others the reply is simple. Indeed, there **are** people who waste everyones time like that. However, I'm not amongst them. I agree with you but arguing about this is like participating in special Olympics (if you know the phrase).

Comment: @KonradViltersten I've asked about it: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/hasty-flag-decline-and-question-close

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I think the point is more that (a) you were googling "riding shotgun" already and (b) if you'd googled for "shotgun", the immediate wikipedia result would have told you explicitly the exact detail that you were questioning (shotgun == "scattergun / pelletgun", for firing "shot" (with a link to its definition, even)).

Comment: @Hellion You absolutely correct. It didn't occur to me that there might be another meaning to "*shot*" so I didn't google for it separately. I must admit that it was a slight notch of arrogance on my part to assume I knew all the possible meanings of said word. To my defense I need to point out that googling and double-checking for **every** word would soon prove quite tedious. Nevertheless, once again, your analysis is very accurate.   :)

Comment: Konrad - Had you asked this question on [ELL.se] instead of ELU, I am confident you would have received the same helpful answer, with a lot more understanding that an English learner doesn't necessarily know every meaning of a particular word, and thus can be easily led off-track. ELL still expects OPs to research their questions, but with the understanding that some simple things aren't always so simple for the novice learner.

Comment: Konrad: first off, I never said this was a *useless* question, only that it was *general reference*. These are two completely orthogonal things. There are lots of useful questions that don't belong on this site. Indeed, *most* useful questions don't. Second off, saying that I fail to realize what non-native speakers think is ludicrous. I *am* a non-native speaker *myself*. And not just any non-native speaker, but one who [campaigned real hard](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/) for a dedicated sister site for non-native speakers. Your comments completely miss the mark.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Please take this in the most polite and respectful way possible but my impression is that you just to conclusions way to much. Perhaps it may behoove us if you took what I write more literally. E.g. I can't recall saying that you judged the question *useless*. E.g. I never said that **you** are (or aren't NSE. And the only point I was trying to make was that the claim that I'm asking while **on purpose** disregarding something (that should be) known to me. That's where you're wrong. I asked around and, in fact, every single person I know was struck by a surprise that *shot* had...

Comment: @RegDwigнt ...that second meaning. So it seems to be unintuitive to check for other meaning on that word. Perhaps **you** didn't get stuck on that because of your excellent linguistic ability. But claiming that I'm on purpose wasting my own and others' time by asking questions that are obviously easy answerable, that's simply insulting. I always do my homework before posting a question. Just because some users have this dyspeptic view that "all" other users are lazy and need to be taught a lesson, doesn't mean it is OK to accuse them of that. It isn't productive so let's just drop the subject.

Comment: @Konrad I asked around and every single person I know knew this meaning of *shot*.

Comment: @KitFox I'm sensing a hidden point but I fail to perceive it fully. Care to elaborate for a tired mind? I see that person A finds a considerable number of occurrences of an event and person B finds an equivalently large (or even significantly larger) set exhibiting lack of said event. Given that the phenomenon in question is a problem that needs to be addressed and that the lack of it needs not, the above situation is equivalent to only the person A's observation. F.i.: "Around 1% of the population suffers hunger." "Well, 99% is satisfied." Can we disregard the (smaller issue) then?

Comment: It's less complicated than that. You are making the claim that because you and all of your companions are unaware of a second meaning of *shot*, you are absolved from looking. In fact, it is precisely because you are unaware of a second meaning, and the first meaning doesn't make sense to you, that you should look first. Anecdotal evidence is insufficient, since it is quite possible that none of your friends has the knowledge you seek.

Comment: @KitFox I see how you figure. However, you need to keep in mind that *shot* made sense "kind-of"-ishly. And checking for every word's possible second meaning is hardly feasible. Especially as I had no reason to suspect that there was a second, "hidden" meaning. It doesn't really matter if the question is closed or not in this particular case. However, such conduct will damage the purposefulness of the site in the long run. And **that** would be really bad. Let's just drop the subject for now and hope that the user learned not to jump to conclusions. We're all friends here, right?  :)

Comment: @Konrad Yes, we are all friends here. I want to make one further point. I agree it is hardly feasible to check for every word's possible second meaning. If the OP doesn't check for their *one* word's second meaning, then EL&U is tasked with checking for *every* word's second meaning, which happens more often than you might think. I hope this helps explain some of the community's reaction to your question.

Comment: @KitFox Point taken. And agreed upon. In the future I'll make sure to check my *one* or *few* words' possible second meanings. This was the first time in my life I hit a word with such an obvious and (to me) well familiar primary meaning and so unknown (to me, still) second one but still so easily accessible definition (once one realizes that a search might be in place). As for the community's reaction, I understand that many sour cases affect the perception of the whole. I also note that the reaction we refer to is limited to a single user being a bit conclusionally jumpy. Great! :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The "shot" in *shotgun* refers to the ammunition that the gun fires. Whereas a pistol or rifle fires ***bullets*** (single metal balls), a shotgun fires a shell packed with [***shot***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_%28pellet%29) (hundreds of tiny metal balls).

Comment: Out of interest, why is it still called a shotgun where it is designed/used to fire slugs and not shot? Is there some kind of historical reason?

Comment: The word "sluggun" wouldn't sound as descriptive.

Comment: @vality: I think the reason is that the style of gun got its name from its capability to fire shot. However, some time after the name for the style of gun was established, firing shot ceased to be the defining characteristic of the type. Hence you can have "shotguns" that primarily or only fire slugs.

Comment: Guns (and cannons) are not the only things that can be shot, such as a shot of whiskey or tequila, so both parts, shot and gun are required to be reasonably specific.

Comment: Aha - my ignorance was the issue here. I thought "*shot*" was a noun of "*to shoot*" and not "*bunch of small pieces*". Cool!

Comment: Exactly - OP was thinking of it a bit backwards. *Gun* doesn't specify the *shot*, *shot* specifies the *gun*.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 Drinking shots out of your gun isn't safe! ;-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby unless it's one of these: http://www.incrediblethings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gun-shot-tequila-2.jpg

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 Thanks... now I keep thinking about people drinking shots of tequila flavoured lead.  *Twitch*

Answer (score 13):

There are other things that shoot 'shot'.  Cannons fired [grapeshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapeshot) as an effective way to deal with infantry.  This makes a 'shotgun' just a gun that shoots shot instead of a cannon that does so.  This clever naming scheme is also visible for 'rifles' which are simply guns with barrels that have been [rifled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rifling).